# assign variables to breakpoints in template

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I would like to assign variables to the Vuetify breakpoints. So instead of writing `xs12` I would like to keep it dynamic and pass in a component prop.

I tried to assign a variable via `xs="myVariable"` and `:xs="myVariable"`. Unfortunately both approaches don't work.

So first I will show a working approach how it should be (with hardcoded values)

https://codepen.io/dunnobutmaybelater/pen/MWYjVPV

Next my dynamic approach

https://codepen.io/dunnobutmaybelater/pen/MWYjVqV

Lastly my approach with `:` before the prop

https://codepen.io/dunnobutmaybelater/pen/povELOd

The code from the codepen is small so I will post it here too:

**HTML**

```
<script type="text/x-template" id="app-template">
  <v-app>
    <v-content>
      <v-container fluid fill-height>
        <v-layout align-center justify-center>
          <v-flex xs="xs" sm="sm" md="md" lg="lg" xl="xl">
            <v-card>
              <v-card-text>
                I'm completely centered
              </v-card-text>
            </v-card>
          </v-flex>
        </v-layout>
      </v-container>
    </v-content>
  </v-app>
</script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

**JS**

```
const App = {
  template: '#app-template',
  data: () => ({
    xs: 12,
    sm: 10,
    md: 8,
    lg: 6,
    xl: 4
  })
}

new Vue({
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```

How can I assign those values with dynamic variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need [dynamic arguments](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Dynamic-Arguments)

```html
<v-flex
  :[`xs${xs}`]="true"
  :[`sm${sm}`]="true"
  :[`md${md}`]="true"
  :[`lg${lg}`]="true"
  :[`xl${xl}`]="true"
>
```

The old components just convert their attributes to classes, so this will work too:

```html
<v-flex :class="['xs' + xs, 'sm' + sm, 'md' + md, 'lg' + lg, 'xl' + xl]">
```

Or use the new grid components (v-layout/v-flex -> v-row/v-col):

```html
<v-col :cols="xs" :sm="sm" :md="md" :lg="lg" :xl="xl">
```

or [shorthand](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#New_notations_in_ECMAScript_2015):

```html
<v-col v-bind="{ cols: xs, sm, md, lg, xl }">
```